# Shouldn't there be a separate call for featured questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I find it rather peculiar that you can sort questions by `featured`. My arguments:

1. What does `order` mean in this case? It *could* mean the bounty amount (e.g. using `desc` would return the questions with the highest bounties first), but it currently doesn't. The lists seem ordered by something else (activity/votes/...?) but I don't know what, I didn't have the time to test that.
2. It would make sense to have a separate call, such as `/questions/featured` because this way one would be able to sort that list by other parameters (sort by bounty, views, votes, ...).

What's your opinion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/questions?sort=featured` is sorted by the date the bounty closes.

Just like the [Featured tab on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured).